# Remove fields from JSON all subpaths in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on qpx-flight api. The response of this Api has lots of 'id' and 'kind' fields. I want to strip those from the response at all paths and subpaths and further down the whole response JSON.

I could enumerate on the, whole response and strip them one at a time in a loop. But I think there must be a simple/elegant way to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic way is to use the [reviver option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) to `JSON.parse`:

```
JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => k === 'id' || k === 'kind' ? undefined : v);
```

Returning `undefined` causes the key/value pair to be omitted from the result.